# W3C Geolocation API Places Database

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Can i get the exact name of a place by providing the latitude and longitudes of a place or do i have to build a database of places based on their longitudes and latitudes first?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Google's Geocoding API.

By doing Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup):

for example make a request for:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452

check http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/.

Cheers

Comment: +1 Google Maps API is certainly the best option out there, however, the only downside is that it requires internet connection, i.e. there's no "Offline" version afaik.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps API can provide detailed information for a location, see http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/. Example: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=37.423021,-122.083739&sensor=false